# Roll-a-ball controller

Tags: c#, unity3d, physics

I've been toying around with Unity 5 lately, and in an effort to start making an actual game, I've built a ball controller similar to the one found in the Unity tutorial [Roll-a-ball](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial).

In essence, the player controls a small ball that rolls around a *"level"*. The ball can accelerate at a rate in the range \$1\rightarrow10\$ depending on what I (the designer) choose. The controller also manually calculates drag to create a *"low-gravity"* feel, but still have a sense of speed. Drag is calculated using the following formula:

$$\text{drag}=\frac{\text{acceleration vector magnitude}}{\text{some dividend}}$$

I'm wondering about the following things:

- Is it appropriate for the controller to do things such as drag calculation, or should this be separated into a separate area?
- I'm currently using a dictionary, looping through it, checking for keypresses, and then applying force if a key is pressed. Is this a good way to handle it? Will this ever slow anything down?
- Are there any performance improvements that can be made?
- Anything else?

**BallController.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// This class contains various methods and attributes
/// used to control the "vehicle".
/// </summary>
[System.Serializable]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class MoveVehicle : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The force of an acceleration. This will be applied
    /// to the ball when it's accelerating.
    /// </summary>
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public float accelerationForce;

    /// <summary>
    /// This determines the drag being exerted on the ball
    /// as it moves. Drag is determined through the formula
    /// drag = accelerationForce / dragDividend
    /// </summary>
    [Range(0, 1000)]
    public float dragDividend;

    private Rigidbody rigidBody;
    private Dictionary<KeyCode, Vector3> keyMappings = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Vector3>() {
        {KeyCode.Space, new Vector3(0, 5.5f, 0)},

        {KeyCode.W, new Vector3(0, 0, 1)},
        {KeyCode.A, new Vector3(-1, 0, 0)},
        {KeyCode.S, new Vector3(0, 0, -1)},
        {KeyCode.D, new Vector3(1, 0, 0)},

        {KeyCode.UpArrow, new Vector3(0, 0, 1)},
        {KeyCode.LeftArrow, new Vector3(-1, 0, 0)},
        {KeyCode.DownArrow, new Vector3(0, 0, -1)},
        {KeyCode.RightArrow, new Vector3(1, 0, 0)}
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the ball is near to, or touching the
    /// ground. This is used to determine whether the
    /// vehicle can move or not.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsGrounded()
    { return Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, -Vector3.up, 0.65f); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize things like our Rigidbody component,
    /// or other things that can only be initialized in
    /// Start.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    { this.rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply thrust to the ball. The faster the vehicle
    /// gets, the more drag we apply to the rigidbody. This will
    /// create the effect of reaching a "maximum" speed.
    /// </summary>
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<KeyCode, Vector3> keyMapping in this.keyMappings)
        {
            if(Input.GetKey(keyMapping.Key) && this.IsGrounded())
            {
                Vector3 objectForce = keyMapping.Value * this.accelerationForce;
                this.rigidBody.drag = objectForce.sqrMagnitude / this.dragDividend;
                this.rigidBody.AddForce(objectForce);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let us nitpick a little bit.

`MoveVehicle` would be a nice name for a method but for a class it isn't choosen well. A class name should be made out of a noun or a noun phrase. So for instance `VehicleMover` or `VehicleController` would be a much better name for this class.

---

The method in question

> ```
> public void FixedUpdate()
> {
>     foreach(KeyValuePair<KeyCode, Vector3> keyMapping in this.keyMappings)
>     {
>         if(Input.GetKey(keyMapping.Key) && this.IsGrounded())
>         {
>             Vector3 objectForce = keyMapping.Value * this.accelerationForce;
>             this.rigidBody.drag = objectForce.sqrMagnitude / this.dragDividend;
>             this.rigidBody.AddForce(objectForce);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

here I would suggest to use `var` rather than `KeyValuePair<KeyCode, Vector3>` which would make your code a little bit cleaner and its obvious that it will be a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue`.

Otherwise your code looks nice and tidy. Good job.

I don't know `Unity3D` at all, so I don't know if it is possible to switch the `public float accelerationForce;` to a public property. If this is possible, I would suggest inside the setter to change all the values of the `Dictionary` so they represent the objectforce. This would involve a second kind of collection or some constants to hold the currently predifined values of the current `Dictionary`.

If it is likely that the `accelerationForce` is called less often than the `FixedUpdate()` method this will speed the whole thing up.

Answer (score 4):

Your file is named `BallController.cs`. Your class is named `MoveVehicle`.

Problem is, both names are wrong. You're not moving a ball or a vehicle. You're moving the a Player. So why isn't your file named `PlayerController.cs`?

If you change the shape of your Player, it's still a Player. But it may no longer be a Ball. PlayerController would be a nice class-name as well. I know it's the standard name used in the tutorial, but it so happens to be a very good one.